# Swift: How do I achieve adding a background color to a tableView textLabel

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, swift5, textlabel

I'm working with TableView and I was hoping to add a background colour to a selected cell's text. Something like this:

The image represents a cell, the background color is separated. This is what is needed.

[image]
I tried doing the following but it adds a background colour to the entire cell or to the text only.

The separation between is the most important, adding a backgroundColor applys a color to the entire cell, which is not wanted.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {  //Highlighting text - Add saving text
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    print("You selected cell number: \(indexPath.row)!")
    cell?.textLabel?.textColor = .yellow
    cell?.textLabel?.backgroundColor = .yellow // Is not desired outcome
}
```

Comment: Its not like that what you think. To be more clear try setting the background color  to `cell` and `textLabel` and then see the difference.

Comment: Actually you need `attributedText` and not the `textColor` only. So google for `attributedText` for label and it will solve your issue. Your question title is misleading.

Comment: `cell?.textLabel?.backgroundColor = .yellow` does not set the entire cell. It sets only the label. Of course it could be that the label is covering most of the cell.

Answer (score 3):

Your image shows a `textlabel` with `yellow` background colour and `black` text colour.

If you are trying to change the background colour, it should be

```
cell?.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
```

`cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.yellow` is used to change the text colour and not the background colour.

( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCc5MKKpfUA . This will help you)

```
let searchString = "Lorem Lorem"
 let baseString = "Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum"



let attributed = NSMutableAttributedString(string: baseString)
    do
    {
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: searchString,options: .caseInsensitive)
        for match in regex.matches(in: baseString, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: baseString.characters.count)) as [NSTextCheckingResult] {
            attributed.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.yellow, range: match.range)
        }
        self.txtView.attributedText = attributed
    }
```

Comment: Hi, this adds a yellow background color to the entire cell, which is not what I want. I need the background color be specific to the text. just like in the picture!

Comment: @N.Der Oh, now i get it. You forgot to mention that your Label fills your entire cell. I am assuming that your label has the same size as the entire cell? By using this, your cell still has white background , but the problem is that your label fills the entire cell and changing label background color makes it look like the cell color changed. For this, you need to use AttributedText

Comment: can you explain searchString and its use

Answer (score 1):

Modify the below code to use as per your requirement

```
 cell?.textLabel?.attributedText = self.decorateText(myTxtOne: "Use this", myTxtTwo: " Code")


func decorateText(myTxtOne:String, myTxtTwo:String)->NSAttributedString{
    let textAttributeOne = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, NSAttributedStringKey.backgroundColor: UIColor.blue, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Poppins-Regular", size: 12.0)!] as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]
let textAttributeTwo = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, NSAttributedStringKey.backgroundColor: UIColor.yellow, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Poppins-Regular", size: 12.0)!] as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]

    let textPartOne = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myTxtOne, attributes: textAttributeOne)
    let textPartTwo = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myTxtTwo, attributes: textAttributeTwo)

    let textCombination = NSMutableAttributedString()
    textCombination.append(textPartOne)
    textCombination.append(textPartTwo)
    return textCombination
}
```

Comment: A good answer provides some explanation. Please don't post code-only answers.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add a global variable for identify which cell is selected.

```
var selectedIndex = -1
```

And update the value according to selected row

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {  //Highlighting text - Add saving text
    self.selectedIndex = indexPath.row
    tabeview.reoadData()
}
```

and write the cellForRow as,

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        var cell= (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier") as! YourCell)

        if self.selectedIndex == indexPath.row
        {
           cell?.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        }
        else
        {
            cell?.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        }

       return cell!
    }
```

Comment: Hi, this adds a yellow background color to the entire cell, which is not what I want. I need the background color be specific to the text. just like in the picture! The separation between is key.

Answer (score 0):

TheTiger user is correct. All you need to learn is setting your label's `attributedText`. I've worked on tons of Bible applications with same highlighting verse feature.

From what I can remember, the attribute name is: `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName`. Good luck!